# Array of Objects is not updating correcting on Event emit in React App

Tags: reactjs, arrays, events

In this I am trying to update the users array to utilise it. Once the user is added  using addUser function from user.js userIsJoined and allUsers events are emitted.Based on this event the state of setusers is being updated which is being sent to Roompage component which is supposed to be displaying current number of users present but for some reason the users array is not getting updated. I am unable to debug why is that happening. Can someone help me out with this. I have to meet a deadline. Thank you in Advance for your help!!
user.js

```
 const users = [];
 const addUser = ({ name, userId, roomId, host, presenter, socketId }) => {
  const user = { name, userId, roomId, host, presenter, socketId };
  users.push(user);
  return users.filter((user) => user.roomId === roomId);
};
```

server.js

```
io.on("connection",(socket) => {
    socket.on("userJoined",(data) =>{
        const {name, userId, roomID, host, presenter} = data;
        roomIDGlobal = roomID;
        socket.join(roomID);
        const users = addUser({name,userId,roomId,host,presenter,socketId: socket.id});
        socket.emit("userIsJoined",{success:true, users});
        socket.emit("allUsers",users); 
        socket.broadcast.to(roomID).emit("whiteBoardDataResponse", {
            imgURL: imgURLGlobal,
        })
    });
```

app.js

```
 const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userIsJoined",(data)=> {
      if(data.success){
        console.log("user has joined the session");
        setUsers(data.users);
        console.log("userIsJoined: ",users);
      }
      else{
        console.log("user joining error");
      }
    });
    socket.on("allUsers",data => {
      setUsers(data);
    });
  
  })
 <Route path="/:roomId" element={<RoomPage user={user} socket = {socket} users={users}/>} />
```

roompage.jsx

```
function RoomPage({user,socket,users}) {
<h1 className='text-center py-4'>
              WHITE BOARD SHARING{" "} 
              <span className="text-primary">[Users Online:{users.length}]</span>
              </h1>}
```

error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at RoomPage (http://localhost:3000/main.5787bccb09c80d85c025.hot-update.js:76:44)
at renderWithHooks

I am expecting the users array to be updated in real time.

Comment: what you indicated as "roompage.js" is not valid JavaScript really.

Comment: It's a typo. Its jsx